# View Messages on Queue

Tags: jms, spring-jms, solace, solace-mq

How can I view/browse the message on the queue programmatically? I don't want to consume the message.

Below is the code I am using to send the message:

```java
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate producerJmsTemplate;

@Value("${.jms.host}")
private String jmsHost;

public void sendMessage(String message, String destQueue) {
    this.producerJmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destQueue, message);
}
```

Comment: Why does it matter how you *send* the message?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JMS then you can use a [QueueBrowser](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html). The [Solace documentation](https://docs.solace.com/Solace-JMS-API/Browsing-Messages.htm) has additional details:

> 1. Create a `QueueBrowser` object.
>
>    Call `Session.createBrowser(...)` and pass in the queue that you want to browse.
>
>    Optionally, you can also pass in a selector string for the Selector property. Using a selector enables the client to only browse messages that match a selector. Note that it could take longer for the message bus to evaluate spooled messages against a selector, especially if the selector used is complex. For more information on selectors, refer to [Selectors](https://docs.solace.com/Solace-JMS-API/Selectors.htm#receiving_messages_3569307012_300923).
> 2. Use the `QueueBrowser` to get an `Enumeration` object that can be used to browse the current queue messages in the order they were received (from oldest to newest) by the queue.
>
>    Call `QueueBrowser.getEnumeration()`.
> 3. Iterate over the messages on the queue.
>
>    Call `Enumeration.hasMoreElements()`. This method returns `true` if there is at least one message available in the browser’s local message buffer; otherwise, it returns `false`.
>
>    If it returns `false`, it does not necessarily mean that the queue is empty, rather the local buffer does not currently contain any messages. Subsequent calls to `Enumeration.hasMoreElements()` or `Enumeration.nextElement()` could return `true` and return a message, respectively.

Comment: I did try.But i always get No messages.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509460/jmstemplate-not-browing-queue-correctly

Comment: If the QueueBrowser returns no messages why do you think there's actually messages on the queue?