# JmsTemplate not browsing queue correctly

Tags: jms, spring-jms, solace, jmstemplate

I am always getting empty list. I have messages on queues which have not been consumed. I am passing the correct queue name.

```java
List<TextMessage> messages = jmsTemplate.browse(destinationQueueName, (session, browser) -> {
    Enumeration<?> browserEnumeration = browser.getEnumeration();
    List<TextMessage> messageList = new ArrayList<TextMessage>();
    while (browserEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        messageList.add((TextMessage) browserEnumeration.nextElement());
    }
    
    return messageList;
});
```

Comment: How do you know there's messages on those queues?

Comment: Is it possible there's something _other than_ a `TextMessage` on the queue? If so, your code would break.

Comment: @JustinBertram because i am sending json string to the queue.No other app is reading the queue

Comment: @JustinBertram This is the code i am using to send message to queue `jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destQueue, message);`
message is a string.

Comment: How do you know that no other app is "reading the queue"?

Comment: If the code is running without any error, you are either reading wrong q or the q is empty. Essentiality configuration error.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the code in question is correct. I used the code successfully in Kotlin to count the number of messages in dead letter queue of an Azure service bus.

```kotlin
var messageCount = 0
serviceBusDeadLetterQueueJmsTemplate.browse("${destination}/\$deadletterqueue") { _, queueBrowser ->
    val browserEnumeration = queueBrowser.enumeration
    while (browserEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        browserEnumeration.nextElement()
        messageCount++
    }
}
return messageCount
```

To find out what is wrong it can help to place a breakpoint inside the callback .